# How to make a vertex with math inside using tkz-graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tkz-graph

Okay, my goal is to make a diagram like this in LaTeX:

[image]

With the difference, that I want where you see `dots` or `dots2`, I want to have `$\ldots$` displayed. I'm trying to get that working using the tkz-graph package. My only experience with tikz is that package, so therefore I'm trying to do this in that way. I know that I can use `\Vertices{line}{0,1,dots,i,i+1,dots2}` to get all the vertices in a line, but I don't know how to get a vertex with math inside. I tried `\Vertices{line}{0,1,$\ldots$,i,i+1,dots2}` but that wont work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {->}}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {draw,
fill = white,
text = black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\Vertices{line}{0,1,dots,i,i+1,dots2}
\Edge[label=q](1)(0)
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend left}}
\Edge[label=p](1)(dots)
\Edge[label=q](dots)(1)
\Edge[label=p](dots)(i)
\Edge[label=q](i)(dots)
\Edge[label=p](i)(i+1)
\Edge[label=q](i+1)(i)
\Edge[label=p](i+1)(dots2)
\Edge[label=q](dots2)(i+1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math` option. But this can't be mixed with other vertices which are not having math content. Hence we have to split the entire line and use `x` and `y` values to position them properly:

```
\Vertices{line}{0,1}
\Vertex[Math,L=\ldots,x=4,y=0] {dots}
\Vertices[x=6,y=0]{line}{i,i+1}
\Vertex[Math,L=\ldots,x=10,y=0] {dots2}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {->}}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {draw,
fill = white,
text = black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\Vertices{line}{0,1}
\Vertex[Math,L=\ldots,x=4,y=0] {dots}
\Vertices[x=6,y=0]{line}{i,i+1}
\Vertex[Math,L=\ldots,x=10,y=0] {dots2}
\Edge[label=q](1)(0)
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend left}}
\Edge[label=p](1)(dots)
\Edge[label=q](dots)(1)
\Edge[label=p](dots)(i)
\Edge[label=q](i)(dots)
\Edge[label=p](i)(i+1)
\Edge[label=q](i+1)(i)
\Edge[label=p](i+1)(dots2)
\Edge[label=q](dots2)(i+1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]